# how do I pass multiple arguments from c++ into a shell script?

Tags: c++, bash, shell

script:

```
export HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE

module load intel64/18.0up03

CMD="mpirun -genv I_MPI_PIN_DOMAIN socket"

EXC="/home/../modular_rom/bin/MPI_MM"

PARAMS="/home/../2D_ISOTROPIC/Snapshots.prm 10 2"

$CMD -np 200 -ppn 20 $EXC $PARAMS
```

c++:

```
AssertThrow(args.size()==12,dealii::ExcMessage("number of parsed parameters has to be 12"));

const std::string snapshot_file = args[0];
const std::string correlation_file = args[1];
const std::string V_file = args[2];
const std::string U_file = args[3];
const std::string eigenvalue_file = args[4];
std::istringstream stream_n_modes(args[5]);
std::istringstream stream_grid_rows(args[6]);
std::istringstream stream_grid_cols(args[7]);
std::istringstream stream_block_size_m(args[8]);
std::istringstream stream_block_size_n(args[9]);
std::istringstream stream_snapshot_dim_1(args[10]);
std::istringstream stream_snapshot_dim_2(args[11]);
```

Above is part of the original code which my tutor gave me. `EXC='..'` is the path of an executable file.What I need to do is to put the 12 arguments into `PARAMS='...'`.How could I achieve that?I'm quite confused since `"/home/../2D_ISOTROPIC/Snapshots.prm 10 2"` seems like a path of a file to me.

Comment: maybe ask your tutor, who gave you the script, instead of a community?

Comment: When you write `$PARAMS` in a shell command, it is subject to space splitting. So every "word" in $PARAMS will be one argument to `$CMD`. Does that help? I am not sure how that is related to your C++ program, however.

Comment: "Good quality" bash scripting would quote everything and use arrays to represent all the multi-arguments: eg `CMD=("mpirun" -genv I_MPI_PIN_DOMAIN socket)` then `"$CMD[@]" -np 200 -ppn 20 "$EXC[@]" "$PARAMS[@]"`

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are separated by spaces. So what you have are 3 parameters already, which are `/home/../2D_ISOTROPIC/Snapshots.prm` (parameter 1), `10` (parameter 2), and `2`, parameter 3.

You just need to add whatever other parameter you need in this list. If your parameter contains space, you'll need to put quotes around it.

Look at this this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/